# How to expose a SOAP web service with authentication in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: web-services, curl, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a SOAP web service and I can make an API call using below command. It works fine.

```
curl --user test:test123 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @checkPayment.xml http://192.168.100.10:8081/asywspay/WSDeclarationPayment
```

Above mentioned SOAP service is exposed via WSO2 API Manager 1.6 and the end-point is `http://api.store.com:8280/WSDeclarationPayment/1.0.` Then I make an API call using below command.

```
curl --user test:test123 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "Authorization: Bearer 7bcc2235a6b0bebfbf4ff684f59f97a7" --data @checkPayment.xml http://api.store.com:8280/WSDeclarationPayment/1.0
```

It gives me error `This request requires HTTP authentication`. Even though I pass the credentials using `--user test:test123` via curl it's not passed through the API Manager.

Given that tried it this way as well.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "Authorization: Bearer 7bcc2235a6b0bebfbf4ff684f59f97a7" --header "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0MTIz" --data @checkPayment.xml http://api.store.com:8280/WSDeclarationPayment/1.0
```

Then I get error `<faultcode>S:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a secured backend SOAP service which needs to be exposed via API Manager. When you create an API, under Endpoints section, you have to click on `Show More Options`, there you have to select `Secured` as `Endpoint Security Scheme`, then you can give the backend service credentials there, as shown in the below image. These credentials will be used when API Manager makes calls to your backend service. Now we have configured the API Manager to communicate with the secured backend.

[image]

Then you have to create an Application in the API Store, subscribe that application to an API, generate access tokens and finally you have to use those access tokens when you invoke an API. This whole flow is well documented here [a]. Please go through it. If you want to invoke your API without access token, you can set `Auth Type` to `None` for an API resource when you create an API.

[a] https://docs.wso2acom/display/AM160/Application+Developer+Guide

Comment: +1 for the answer. I followed the exact same steps then I get this error `<faultcode>S:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {` Why is that?

Comment: Do you see any errors in API Manager logs ($AM_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log) ?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the logs. Do you have any idea how this can be fixed?